# Should rvalue reference qualifier return rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am investigating whether returning rvalue reference from rvalue ref-qualifier function is really good idea. Lets say we have:

```
class DataPack {
 public:
  std::vector<int> data;

  DataPack(std::initializer_list<int> d) : data{d} {}

  std::vector<int>& get_data() & {
    return data;
  }
  std::vector<int>&& get_data() && {
    return std::move(data);
  }
  // This version fixes for-loop problem (see below)
  //std::vector<int> get_data() && {
  //  return data;
  //}
};
```

then if I want to get data without making temporary I can use following:

```
auto my_data = DataPack{1,2,3}.get_data();
```

but suppose I want to use following code:

```
for (auto v : DataPack{1,2,3}.get_data()) {
  std::cout << v << ", ";
}
```

now this is UB, as get_data() returns reference to temporary which is destroyed after full statement.

Maybe this can be somehow fixed for such for - loops? Or maybe we should return by value and hope that RVO will work as expected? Becasue as it is above seems to me as not very safe.

Comment: Why do you even have `get_data()` in the first place? Just using `data` would be enough. But yes, you'd want to return by value.

Comment: I fail to see the UB. Could anyone cite why this is UB? `DataPack` isn't actually moved out.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Internally the `for` captures the range-expression with `auto&&`, so it turns into `auto&& __expr = DataPack{1,2,3}.get_data()`. The problem is that at the end of this expression the `DataPack` is destroyed, so `__expr` becomes a dangling reference.

Comment: @ildjarn Right, it seems obvious now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: For this use case perhaps you could have a function `make_data_pack(1,2,3);` returning the `vector<int>` . Then you have compulsory copy elision (as of c++17).

Comment: @T.C. I was reading item 12 from Scot Meyers Effective Modern C++, and there  is an example similar to above one. I was trying to find how to make use of ref-qualifiers in my code, and actually I dont see many uses now. Even in gcc6.3 includes I can see only uses of ref-qualifiers in optional header, and they all return constexpr rvalue references.

Comment: Ultra-generic code like `optional` and code returning concrete types like `vector<int>` are very different. In the former case you don't actually know the cost of moving and copying; in the latter case you do. In any event, my point is that if you have member functions like this exposing a mutable reference to a data member directly, you might as well just use the data member and get rid of the member function. Then lifetime extension will work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>&& get_data() && {
   return std::move(data);
}
```

This should return a `std::vector<int>` instead, then there's no problem.